# Google BigQuery without billing

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to use the service without setting up the billing ?

Doesn't seem to be working for me, even if I'm well below the free quotas. I kept getting the 403 response, "Billing has not been enabled for this project." until I have enabled the billing.

I would still like to know if it's possible, since I have to setup a demo project and I would prefer not to use my personal account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use BigQuery without setting up billing. However, you are limited to querying publicly available data (data that is shared with "All authenticated users") and cannot load your own data or export data.

If you enable billing and stay within the free query tier, you'll only pay for storage, which for small tables may be a trivial amount (if you have 1 GB of data that is less than $0.03 per month).

Comment: Thanks ! I was a bit confused since I have found in the documentation that it is indeed possible, but couldn't figure out why it didn't worked.